# Why is this black line appearing on my mesh when I render?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I am new in Blender and  I can't understand why rendering goes wrong?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to check normals with Ctrl+N in Edit mode